# Creating multiple structs in one for loop

Tags: c++

So I have a loop that goes something like

```
for (r = 0; r < k; r++) {
    pair p = {r, D[r]};
    queue.push(p);
}
```

where pair is defined as

```
struct pair {
    int u;
    float d;
}
```

Is this a legal way to create k pairs and push them onto a priority queue?  Do the pairs still exist on the queue in their original form even though p gets overwritten each time?  Or does each pair that's already on the queue get automatically updated to the new value of p, resulting in a queue full of identical copies of the same pair?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is fine.

`p` gets *copied* into the queue; it doesn't matter what happens to the original after the copy is made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code works as is. The default copy constructor of `p` is called, and a copy is pushed into `queue`. However, you can simplify your code a bit by adding a constructor. If you define `pair` as:

```
struct pair {
    pair(int u_, float d_) : u(u_), d(d_){}
    int u;
    float d;
};
```

Then in your loop, you can simply do:

```
for (r = 0; r < k; r++) {
    queue.push_back(pair(r, D[r]));
}
```

That way, it is a bit more clear that you are intentionally pushing a copy. Also, make sure you have a `;` after the end of your struct declaration! If you forget, you can end up with some mysterious compiler errors.